# Make multi thread http request in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, http, python-requests

I'm trying to write a XSS scanner to find unfiltered character that can be used in requests parameter. The problem here is the code runs to slow because lots of http requests that has to be send.
Here is the code:

```
from time import sleep
import requests
import urllib.parse
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import argparse

urllib3.disable_warnings()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="XSS Scanner")

parser.add_argument("-u", "--url",
                    required=True,
                    help='Specify the URL.')

parser.add_argument("-t", "--threads",
                    default=5,
                    type=int,
                    help='Number of threads to send HTTP requests.')

parser.add_argument("-o", "--output",
                    default=False,
                    action="store",
                    help='Use this switch if you want to store data to a file.')

parser.add_argument("-s", "--sleep",
                    default=False,
                    action="store",
                    type=int,
                    help='Use this switch if you want to have time interval.')

options = parser.parse_args()


def send_request(url):
    response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, verify=False)
    return response.content


def extract_forms_names(url_response):
    extracted_names = []

    forms = BeautifulSoup(url_response, features='lxml').find_all('form')
    for form in forms:
        for field in form:
            try:
                if field.has_attr('name'):
                    extracted_names.append(field['name'])
            except:
                pass
    return extracted_names


def extract_javascript_variables(Target_response):
    regex_pattern = r'(?:var|const|let)\s+(\w+)'
    extracted_variables = re.findall(
        regex_pattern, Target_response.decode('UTF-8'))
    return extracted_variables

Time_interval = options.sleep
Thread_num = options.threads
# Target_url = 'https://brutelogic.com.br/gym.php'
Target_url = options.url
Target_response = send_request(Target_url)

extracted_names = extract_forms_names(Target_response)
extracted_variables = extract_javascript_variables(Target_response)
extracted_parameters = extracted_names + extracted_variables

reflected_parameters = []

for parameter in extracted_parameters:
    request_url = f'{Target_url}?{parameter}=NOOB'
    response = send_request(request_url).decode('UTF-8')
    sleep(Time_interval)
    if 'NOOB' in response:
        reflected_parameters.append(parameter)

allowed_character_parameters = []
check_characters = ['"', "'", ">", "<", "{", "}", ";", ":", "&"]
try:
    with open(options.output,'w') as output_file:    
        for parameter in reflected_parameters:
            parameter_details = {
                "parameter": parameter,
                "allowed_characters": []
            }
            for character in check_characters:
                payload = f'NOOB{character}'
                url_encoded_payload = urllib.parse.quote(payload)
                request_url = f'{Target_url}?{parameter}={url_encoded_payload}'
                response = send_request(request_url).decode('UTF-8')
                sleep(Time_interval)
                if payload in response:
                    parameter_details['allowed_characters'].append(character)
            allowed_character_parameters.append(parameter_details)
            print(parameter_details)
            output_file.write(str(parameter_details)+'\n')
except:
    for parameter in reflected_parameters:
            parameter_details = {
                "parameter": parameter,
                "allowed_characters": []
            }
            for character in check_characters:
                payload = f'NOOB{character}'
                url_encoded_payload = urllib.parse.quote(payload)
                request_url = f'{Target_url}?{parameter}={url_encoded_payload}'
                response = send_request(request_url).decode('UTF-8')
                sleep(Time_interval)
                if payload in response:
                    parameter_details['allowed_characters'].append(character)
            allowed_character_parameters.append(parameter_details)
            print(parameter_details)
```

I want to send multi threads http requests in these sections to speed up the code:

```
for parameter in extracted_parameters:
    request_url = f'{Target_url}?{parameter}=NOOB'
    response = send_request(request_url).decode('UTF-8')
    sleep(Time_interval)
    if 'NOOB' in response:
        reflected_parameters.append(parameter)
```

```
for parameter in reflected_parameters:
            parameter_details = {
                "parameter": parameter,
                "allowed_characters": []
            }
            for character in check_characters:
                payload = f'NOOB{character}'
                url_encoded_payload = urllib.parse.quote(payload)
                request_url = f'{Target_url}?{parameter}={url_encoded_payload}'
                response = send_request(request_url).decode('UTF-8')
                sleep(Time_interval)
                if payload in response:
                    parameter_details['allowed_characters'].append(character)
            allowed_character_parameters.append(parameter_details)
            print(parameter_details)
```

Example of the way to run the code:

```
 python xssScanner.py -u https://brutelogic.com.br/gym.php -t 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do `request.get()` you reopen the connection.
if you have to do multiple gets on same host you could create a session

```
mySession = requests.Session()
```

and then

```
def send_request(url):
    response = mySession.get(url, allow_redirects=True, verify=False)
    return response.content
```

Comment: You're right but my point is for example sending 10 get requests at the same time using concurrent.futures library or threading library and I'm confused about how to implement it in my code

Comment: You could create a session in each thread and pass as a parameter to `send_request`